# App crashes after Android OS update. How to solve it?

Tags: android, operating-system, crash, android-os-handler

while developing the currently serviced app, the user's problem continues to be checked.

I'd like to ask if anyone has had a similar problem or knows how to do it.

1. App closes after OS update
2. After running the app, the checked log progresses to the onResume state and then ends
3. When checking with the debug version in the application, no crash is confirmed in the application
4. Samsung has been informed that there may be a webview issue related to the dual messenger after the Android 12 update.

My error :

```
12-09 12:42:09.827 10400 17425 17425 E chromium: [ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
12-09 12:42:09.827 10400 17425 17425 F libc    : Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x76e0b0f36c in tid 17425, pid 17425 (tmicro.kidsnote)  
12-09 12:42:13.612 10400 18329 18329 E chromium: [ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
12-09 12:42:13.612 10400 18329 18329 F libc    : Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x76e0b0f36c in tid 18329 (tmicro.kidsnote), pid 18329 (tmicro.kidsnote)
```

Comment: Hi. can you add you crash Stack Trace?

Comment: `12-09 12:42:09.827 10400 17425 17425 E chromium: [ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
12-09 12:42:09.827 10400 17425 17425 F libc    : Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x76e0b0f36c in tid 17425, pid 17425 (tmicro.kidsnote)
 
12-09 12:42:13.612 10400 18329 18329 E chromium: [ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
12-09 12:42:13.612 10400 18329 18329 F libc    : Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x76e0b0f36c in tid 18329 (tmicro.kidsnote), pid 18329 (tmicro.kidsnote)`

Comment: @YoavGibri
Thanks for your comment. This is what you requested.